# Batch downloading with Start-Job and Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I've got the current code:

```
$installers = @{
    "vagrant.msi" = "https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.0.0/vagrant_2.0.0_x86_64.msi";
    "chrome.exe" = "https://dl.google.com/tag/s/defaultbrowser/chrome/install/ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe";
}

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

foreach ($i in $installers.GetEnumerator()) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Invoke-WebRequest $($using:i.Value) -Method Get -OutFile "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\$($using:i.Name)"
    }
}

Get-Job|Wait-Job
```

I believe that this should download both of the files to Downloads simultaneously. Both jobs seem to run, but at the end of it I've only got `chrome.exe`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to move the `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` line inside the `Start-Job` block:

```
foreach ($i in $installers.GetEnumerator()) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        Invoke-WebRequest $($using:i.Value) -Method Get -OutFile "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\$($using:i.Name)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first value is not going inside. So you should use the param and argumentlist for the *start-job*

Try this:

```
$installers = @{
    "vagrant.msi" = "https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.0.0/vagrant_2.0.0_x86_64.msi";
    "chrome.exe" = "https://dl.google.com/tag/s/defaultbrowser/chrome/install/ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe";
}

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

foreach ($i in $installers.GetEnumerator()) 
{
    $value=$i.Value
    $Downloadpath="$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\$($i.Name)"
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($value,$Downloadpath)Invoke-WebRequest $value -Method Get -OutFile $Downloadpath} -ArgumentList $value,$Downloadpath
}

Get-Job|Wait-Job
```

Note: It seems that the First Job is failing . Just cross check it once

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @SmallHadronCollider: I gave the reason. The job is failing. Only Chrome is getting downloaded. If I am using any other URL then it is working.

Comment: The first job was failing because the `SecurityProtocol` line was in the wrong place. It works if you move it inside the `ScriptBlock`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @SmallHadronCollider: Great. Acceptance/Upvote of the answer would be appreciable.